# FlowLayout with adapter in android

Tags: android, flowlayout

I am looking for any library that help me to make a FlowLayout with adapter, like GridView, but i want to arrange elements in flow! What do you think, what is the best way to do that (FreeFlow)?
I have created a StickyListHeadersListView with adapter:

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position,  View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    FiltersChildViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        final View[] temp = new View[1];
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             temp[0] = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_filters_layout, parent, false);
            }
        });
      convertView = temp[0];

        holder = new FiltersChildViewHolder();
        holder.flFilters_IFL = (FlowLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flFilters_IFL);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (FiltersChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    ArrayList<FilterModel> filterModels = getFiltersForCategory(position);

    FilterLayoutAdapter adapter = new FilterLayoutAdapter(mActivity, filterModels);
    adapter.setOnFiltersChangedListener(mFiltersChangedListener);
    adapter.setIsDefault(isDefault);
    holder.flFilters_IFL.setAdapter(adapter);

    return convertView;
}
```

This is the getView() method in my adapter! Every list item is a FlowLayout, and the FilterLayoutAdapter will add views to this FlowLayout, this works for me, in this way the elements are arranged in flow, but the ListView is very freezy when I scroll to the next list item, because all childView are inflated immediatelly in FlowLayout and thera are 100 childView!

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is example using  **custom Library** which acts like List [GitHubLibrary TagLayout](https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout)

- **Sample Code**:-

`mFlowLayout.setAdapter(new TagAdapter<String>(mVals)
   {
       @Override
       public View getView(FlowLayout parent, int position, String s)
       {
           TextView tv = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tv,
                   mFlowLayout, false);
           tv.setText(s);
           return tv;
       }
   });`

**Using below code you can pre set selection you wanted:**-

```
mAdapter.setSelectedList(1,3,5,7,8,9);
```

**Will show result like below:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code of section at the end of getView method before 
`return view;` line.

```
Animation animationY = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                        parent.getHeight() / 4, 0);
                animationY.setDuration(1000);
                view.startAnimation(animationY);
```

where parent will be

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent)
```

Comment: I don't understand, how it will solve my problem! My problem is that, every list item is a FlowLayout, every FlowLayout will have min 30 childs and when I inflate them, they are inflated immediatelly and this blocks the main thread, because i used ListView.I think that would work with GridView, but GridView does not arrange elements in flow!

Comment: FlowLayout is a custom ViewGroup, it arranges elements in flow like FlowLayout in Java! For example : https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout